# QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QWidget

Tags: qt, dll, runtime-error

So I'm having this problem with the error above and this is what is in the console:
@QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QWidget
Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.@

This is my main(), if you need more code I will post more:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{     
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    streamwindow w;
    QIcon icon(":/stuff/twitch_final.png");
    w.setWindowIcon(icon);
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

What happens is it compiles the program fine, I can build it just fine, but when it comes time to actually run it is when it gives me the error.

[image]

I ran dependency walker and this is what I found.

[image]

Comment: Hi, did you include `#include <QApplication>` ?

Comment: Do you have the same error if you replace streamwindow by QMainWinwow? If not, you must add streamwindow code to your post. If you do a step by step debugging, which line causes the assertion?

Comment: Aren't you initializing any global variable with a `QWidget` instance (using dynamic initialization)?